# Can Allomancers see metal behind themselves?

Tags: magical-theory, cosmere, mistborn

The blue lines that iron and steel Mistings see point towards nearby metal objects whenever an Allomancer is burning one of the two metals. They can see these lines even when they close their eyes. Interestingly, they could be blind or have their eyes are gouged out, they can still see sources of metal that would otherwise be in their field of vision.

However, what I'm wondering is, is there any textual evidence that says whether or not Allomancers can see the lines that aren't in their field of vision, like lines pointing behind them?

Comment: im fairly sure i remember mentions of sensing metal moving behind in the wax and wayne novels but i dont have an exact quote

Comment: In theory, you could even jab just metal spikes through their eyes clean through their head, and they would still be able to see things if they were strong enough with allomancy.

Comment: @Antheloth, in _"The Bands of Mourning"_ a beggar throws a coin at Wax from behind and he turns and catches it.

Comment: @JMac Or if the spikes undergo an appropriate treatment beforehead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes

At least that is the implication in the text.

> As they walked through the quiet streets, Vin reached tentatively inside. She eyed Kelsier, then carefully burned that unknown metal. Again, the lines sprang up around her, pointing in seemingly random directions.
>
> The lines moved with her. One end of each thread stayed stuck to her chest, while the other end remained attached to a given place along the street. New lines appeared as she walked, and **old ones faded, disappearing behind.** The lines came in various widths, and some of them were brighter than others.
> <sub>*The Final Empire - Chapter 7*</sub>

Additionally, there are many references to Allomancers Pushing/Pulling on something behind them for support. Not to mention that pushing to jump requires the metal to be at least beneath them, if not behind them. So clearly, they are able to sense metal that is not within their direct line of sight.

> Vin burned steel, Pushing herself into the cold, humid autumn night. Tin enhanced her eyes, making the wet air tickle her throat as she breathed. **She Pushed hard behind her**
> <sub>*The Final Empire - Chapter 13*</sub>

> Once she landed on the damp stone, **she reached behind and Pulled** the bar up into her hand.
> <sub>*The Final Empire - Chapter 13*</sub>

> He’s so strong! Vin thought with horror. [The Inquisitor] was **probably steadying himself by Pulling against the lantern brackets behind**.
> <sub>*The Final Empire - Chapter 14*</sub>

> Kelsier flared iron — **stabilizing himself by Pulling against a lantern bracket behind** — then grabbed the iron studs on Demoux’s vest.
> <sub>*The Final Empire - Chapter 21*</sub>

> Vin flared steel, Pushing herself up a bit higher, **then flung another coin into the mists behind her. When it hit the wall, she used it to shoot herself forward.**
> <sub>*The Final Empire - Chapter 23*</sub>

> Good enough, Vin thought. With a flare of steel, she threw herself into the air, **Pushing against a massive iron door behind her.**
> <sub>*The Final Empire - Chapter 30*</sub>

> Kelsier **Pulled the bars behind him** and Pushed the ones in front of him, sending a stream of metal shooting toward the Inquisitor.
> <sub>*The Final Empire - Chapter 34*</sub>

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>